# java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [config/foo.yml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am upgrading my spring boot application from 1.3 to 2.1, I am able to do `mvn compile` and build success.

But while running the application I am getting the below error

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [config/foo.yml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

My config properties class

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:/config/foo.yml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "config")
public class FooProperties {

    private String errorCode;

    public String getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }

    public void setErrorCode(String errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }
}
```

foo.yml is present under src/main/resources/config/foo.yml only and yml file name is correct

foo.yml content

```
config:
  name: foo
```

I have seen many posts related to the same error but it didn't help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try with add `*` after  `classpath` to let it can search more locations, so change it to

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath*:/config/foo.yml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
```

or

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath*:config/foo.yml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
```

Comment: @LearnToCode have you made `src/main/resources` it as a resource folder?

Comment: I am using intelliJ and I see src/main/resources folder marked as Resources Root

Comment: I tried to use this @ImportResource("classpath*:/config/foo.yml") and the issue got fixed

Comment: @LearnToCode Great for your problem to be solved